# Optimal way to maintain two hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, distcp, bigdata

Can I get the advantages & disadvantages of transfering data from a database

- to two separate hdfs clusters at once
- to one hdfs cluster then use distcp to move the data to the second cluster